# Columns Appear under Each Other in Footer

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

Columns appear below each other in the footer. Tried id'ing each column and adding 'float: left' in each one -- didn't make any difference. And it appears that it's not the only conflict there as even the h4 header is displayed as paragraph... 
Site: http://e54.5b1.myftpupload.com/

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4>Header 1</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4>Header 2</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Line 1</li>
            <li>Line 2</li>
            <li>Line 3</li>
            <li>Line 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4>Header 3</h4>
        <ul>
            <li>Line 1</li>
            <li>Line 2</li>
            <li>Line 3</li>
            <li>Line 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="footerFloat">
        <h4>Header 4</h4>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS style:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;    
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: auto;
} 

#footer {
    width: 100%;
} 

.footerFloat {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Looking at http://jsfiddle.net/q87egpLs/ (which is just a copy of your code), all looks good.

Comment: You are right Darren, I think there is no need to change anything. Just make sure you have put above code in <style></style> tag properly.

Comment: Danj, I went through your website via developer tool. But I couldn't see above CSS code in any of the resource file you using.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/3u5qrL4k/

```
.footerFloat {
width: 25%;
float: left;
}
```

You do not have your .footerFloat class present in your css on your page http://e54.5b1.myftpupload.com/

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why people is saying your code is right when is CLEARLY wrong. You have quite a bunch of errors, check [HTML Validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fe54.5b1.myftpupload.com%2F) . Basically, you have several unclosed elements, the most important of which is nothing less than the... head section. Check lines 683 to 698 and you'll see the header and nav inside the unclosed head, then the body, then a slider... well, quite a mess. Anyways, check out that link and go through each error and you'll easily fix everything